# SambaShare openVPN transfer speed

Tags: networking, server, samba, vpn, openvpn

I made the openVPN settings of my TPLink archer vr2100 modem and I can connect to my samba server over the internet (from another network). But I can transfer between 300-500 kilobytes per second. My server download speed 40 mbps and my client download speed 25mbps when I connect to vpn from client my download speed decreasing to 900kbps what can I do for ıncrease file transfer speed?

Comment: From the openvpn web site. An OpenVPN tunnel also requires approximately 25% of the tunnel's total speed in overhead, so if the maximum bandwidth of the tunnel is 10 Mbps, you likely will not see more than ~8 Mbps. And that is a best case situation.

Comment: Thank you for  comment I have a one more question Is there anything else I can use other than openVPN. I need to connect to my server remotely.

Comment: Most VPNs do not allow that. I did a fair bit of research before choosing a VPN and went for speed and security at the loss of remote access to my network. Good luck.